# Protractor: How to keep browser instance running after one spec execution is over

Tags: javascript, protractor

We have an application, which has multiple feature to be validated.
I have created several protractor specs created to test individual feature. The application requires user to login to it before giving access to features. For this, I have one more spec which will open the browser and login to the application.
Expectation is, other specs will use this session, which is created and authenticated by login spec, for their validation.
But as soon as the login spec gets over, browser session gets closed.

When I create a session from http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html location and give it in conf.js file under attribute name seleniumSessionId, then the session does not get closed.
But I need to create this session from login script, so that this manual work of creating session and passing it in conf.js file can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is, I have in my config file `onPrepare()` function where I do the logging:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get(browser.params.url);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginInput')).sendKeys('login');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys('password');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('submitButton')).click();
    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
       return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
         return true;
       });
    }, 30000);
}
```

If for some reason your website closes session after reloading page (which would be weird), you can move this code to your `beforeEach()` function, or even in your config file attach it to your global object and use it anywhere in your tests.

```
global.loginToPage = function() {
   browser.driver.get...
}
```

And in your tests call it as a standard function.

Answer (score 0):

So what you'll need to do is pass the session id:

```
protractor spec.js --seleniumSessionId=<session id>
```

There is an example of this in Protractor. In [scripts/attachSession.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/scripts/attachSession.js), the file makes a request to the selenium standalone server and creates a new session. After the session is created, it runs the Protractor test. Because you provide the session, [Protractor will not close down the session](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/attachSession.ts#L53), you are responsible for sending the delete session request.

Also note that you could add the `seleniumSessionId` flag could also be a property in your protractor config.

(huzzah a feature I wrote earlier this year)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I need to create browser session in one spec. and it should continue in other specs also.  If I call the functions defined in scripts/attachSession.js in my test spec, will it persist after the spec execution is finished..

Comment: With the `seleniumSessionId` the browser window will never close. The downside is if you encounter an error, the rest of your tests would probably fail or could give false positives after it encounters your first failure. You could also do a beforeEach to login each time with an afterEach to logout. The downside to that your tests will take more time.

Answer (score 0):

Put before eeach function to login and then put the tests in "it" blocks

```
describe('tests', function() {

beforeEach(function(done) {

    loginPage.Login();       

});


    it('should test something', function() {


    });
});
```